# How to get touch movement outside?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, touch

I can get the coordinates in ACTION_OUTSIDE of onTouchEvent but it doesn't update so I have to get MOVE of OUTSIDE
please tell me

Comment: Before asking a question kindly show us what have you done to solve this problem? Also, post your code so we can help further with the help of code.

Answer (score 0):

*Question isnt so clear. But here is what i got.*

**So here's the plan:**

1. Get Last Coordinates when ACTION_MOVE is called and store them as variables
2. Use Coordinates when ACTION_OUTSIDE is called